# How to render SVG image to PNG file in Python?

Tags: python, linux, svg, render

So I want to render SVG from python code having target resolution WxH (having SVG text as str, [like this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feDisplacementMap) that I generate dynamically):

```
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 220 220"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <filter id="displacementFilter">
    <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.05"
        numOctaves="2" result="turbulence"/>
    <feDisplacementMap in2="turbulence" in="SourceGraphic"
        scale="50" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G"/>
  </filter>

  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100"
      style="filter: url(#displacementFilter)"/>
</svg>
```

into a png image. How to do such a thing in Python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert SVG to PNG in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589358/convert-svg-to-png-in-python)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

there are multiple solutions available for converting svgs to pngs in python, but not all of them will work for your particular use case since you're working with svg filters.

| solution | filter works? | alpha channel? | call directly from python? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cairosvg | some* | yes | yes |
| svglib | no | [no](https://github.com/deeplook/svglib/issues/171) | yes |
| inkscape | yes | yes | via `subprocess` |
| wand | yes | yes | yes |

* from [cairosvg documentation](https://cairosvg.org/documentation/#colors-gradients-patterns-clipping-masking-filtering-compositing):

> Only `feOffset`, `feBlend` and `feFlood` filters are supported.

---

note: i've added a solid white background to all the sample images to make them easier to see on a dark background, the originals did have transparent backgrounds unless stated in the table above

---

[cairosvg](https://cairosvg.org/)

[image: output from cairosvg]

```py
import cairosvg

# read svg file -> write png file
cairosvg.svg2png(url=input_svg_path, write_to=output_png_path, output_width=width, output_height=height)

# read svg file -> png data
png_data = cairosvg.svg2png(url=input_svg_path, output_width=width, output_height=height)

# svg string -> write png file
cairosvg.svg2png(bytestring=svg_str.encode(), write_to=output_png_path, output_width=width, output_height=height)

# svg string -> png data
png_data = cairosvg.svg2png(bytestring=svg_str.encode(), output_width=width, output_height=height)
```

---

[svglib](https://pypi.org/project/svglib/)

[image: output from svglib]

```py
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
from reportlab.graphics import renderPM

# read svg -> write png
renderPM.drawToFile(svg2rlg(input_svg_path), output_png_path, fmt='PNG')
```

---

[inkscape](https://inkscape.org/)

[image: output from inkscape]

to read a file as input, put the path to the file as the last argument.
to use a string as input, add the `--pipe` argument and pass the string to stdin.

to write to a file as output, add the argument `--export-filename=`+path to output file.
to get the output contents directly without writing to a file, use `--export-filename=-` and it will be sent to stdout instead.

full documentation for CLI options [here](https://inkscape.org/doc/inkscape-man.html)

```py
import subprocess
inkscape = ... # path to inkscape executable

# read svg file -> write png file
subprocess.run([inkscape, '--export-type=png', f'--export-filename={output_png_path}', f'--export-width={width}', f'--export-height={height}', input_svg_path])

# read svg file -> png data
result = subprocess.run([inkscape, '--export-type=png', '--export-filename=-', f'--export-width={width}', f'--export-height={height}', input_svg_path], capture_output=True)
#   (result.stdout will have the png data)

# svg string -> write png file
subprocess.run([inkscape, '--export-type=png', f'--export-filename={output_png_path}', f'--export-width={width}', f'--export-height={height}', '--pipe'], input=svg_str.encode())

# svg string -> png data
result = subprocess.run([inkscape, '--export-type=png', '--export-filename=-', f'--export-width={width}', f'--export-height={height}', '--pipe'], input=svg_str.encode(), capture_output=True)
#   (result.stdout will have the png data)
```

---

[wand](https://docs.wand-py.org/)

[image]

```py
from wand.image import Image
from wand.Color import Color

with Color('#00000000') as bgcolor,\
  # to read input from a file:
  Image(filename=input_svg_path, width=width, height=height, background=bgcolor) as img:
  # or, to use input from a string:
  Image(blob=svg_str.encode(), format='svg', width=width, height=height, background=bgcolor) as img:
    # to save output to a file:
    with img.convert('png') as output_img:
        output_img.save(filename=output_png_path)
    # or, to get the output data in a variable:
    png_data = img.make_blob(format='png')
```

Comment: Nice overview! [With my workaround from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74164750/1506569) you can also get `svglib` to support alpha channels (using `pymupdf`) without any external dependencies (at least on Windows/Linux/Mac) with the prebuilt wheels.

Comment: Side question: can ANY of these methods, apart from inkscape, properly render <image> elements into a PNG, and does that include jpg and webp?

Answer (score 6):

you can use [CairoSVG](https://cairosvg.org/)

CairoSVG is available on PyPI, you can install it with pip:

```
pip3 install cairosvg
```

in your code:

```
import cairosvg

width = 640
height = 480
cairosvg.svg2png(url='logo.svg', write_to='image.png', output_width=width, output_height=height)
```